# using sql distinct to retrieve same column from two different database tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question, and I can't seem to find any lead on this. I am looking to retrieve the same column from two tables in the database, e.g. User and UserGroup.

If I were to select John from the User Table, John will be displayed in the UserGroup Table, and in the User Table, John will no longer be displayed. Is it possible to even do a query like that??

```
User
 1. John
 2. Jane
 3. Tom

User Group
 Empty
```

After selection of John:

```
User
 2. Jane
 3. Tom

User Group
 1. John
```

Instead of having the following (which I have now):

```
User

 1. John
 2. Jane
 3. Tom
```

After Selection of John:

```
UserGroup

 1. John
```

The only possible way I can think of right now is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
JOIN 
usuarios_grupos
ON
(usuarios_grupos.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario)
```

However, I ran the query, and it doesn't give me the ideal result. Any thoughts on this??

I did UNION ALL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios_grupos.id_usuario
FROM usuarios_grupos
```

and I got the following result:

```
 1. John 
 2. Jane
 3. Tom
 4. John
 5. Jane
 6. Tom
```

Comment: what's your query? use a `UNION ALL`

Comment: Do you mean you want to move the data between tables in some manner?

Comment: No.Instead of showing Johns in both tables,is it possible to show John just in 1 table?? I know it sounds odd, but my 2nd table is populated based on the selection of my first table

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. Selecting doesn't alter the tables selected from. Please show a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/), which includes table schema (`CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and desired query results for the sample data using a standard MySQL output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two queries might do what you expect, the first show all users except those in the second:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
WHERE id_usario NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_usuario FROM usuarios_grupos)
```

And the second

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios_grupos.id_usuario
FROM usuarios_grupos
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've been looking for !! THANK YOU SO MUCHHH

Answer (score 0):

Would something like

```
SELECT t2.id_usuario FROM usuarios t2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT usuarios_grupos.id_usuario FROM usuarios_grupos) t1
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios_grupos.id_usuario
FROM usuarios_grupos
WHERE id_usuario NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios)
```

This should give you values from `usuarios` and values from `usuarios_grupos` that don't exist in `usuarios` ..